# What is the minimum amount of java I should know build android apps via eclipse/android studio IDE

Tags: android

I' am currently reading a book on java, well....actually I' m read ahead because this Monday (June 23, 2014) I have a Java beginner programming class for summer semester. According to my professor for the 6 week course we'll be covering the following:

**Chapter 1 Introduction to Computers, Programming, and Java
-Chapter 2 Elementary Programming
-Chapter 3 Selections
-Chapter 4 Loops
-Chapter 5 Methods
-Chapter 6 Single-Dimensional Arrays
-Chapter 7 Multidimensional Arrays
-Chapter 8 Objects and Classes
-Chapter 9 Strings
-Chapter 10 Thinking in Objects
-Chapter 11 Inheritance and Polymorphism
-Chapter 12 GUI Basics**

Also in fall semester 2014, I already signed up for the java advanced class which features the following chapters:

**Chapter 13 Graphics
Chapter 14 Exception Handling and Text I/O
Chapter 15 Abstract Classes and Interfaces
Chapter 16 Event-Driven Programming
Chapter 17 GUI Componenets
Chapter 18 Applets and Multimedia
Chapter 19 Binary I/O
Chapter 20 Recursion
Chapter 21 Generics
Chapter 22 Lists, Stacks, Queues, and Priority Queues
Chapter 23 Sets and Maps
Chapter 24 Developing Efficient Algorithms
Chapter 25 Sorting
Chapter 26 Implementing Lists, Stacks, Queues, and Priority Queues
Chapter 27 Binary Search Trees
Chapter 28 Hashing
Chapter 29 AVL Trees
Chapter 30 Graphs and Applications
Chapter 31 Weighted Graphs and Applications
Chapter 32 Multithreading and Parallel Programming
Chapter 33 Networking
Chapter 34 Java Database Programming**

Now I was wondering how many chapters should i go up to in order to start building android apps? Also, I know JavaScript and PHP, but tiny XML, and I've noticed XML files in android app builds? why is this? would I be able to substitute the xml data using JSON instead?

Comment: how is your approach to other programming languages​​? do you know about object oriented programming?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning Java / Android and not a specific programming problem

Comment: it's pretty complicated and not a good place to start if you're only a beginner, but if you are determined then you can still handle it.  You might not immediately understand all the concepts but you should be able to write some code and learn as you go.

Comment: You really need to understand memory allocation/garbage collecting and data types as far as Java is concerned. Once you have got that down and understand how everything is linked together in Java, Android will be much easier.

Comment: @Azincourt I know JavaScript and PHP, and currently practicing/learning JavaScript OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple answer to this, as android app development covers a lot of different skills.

"the minimum amount" is in my opinion not a lot, if you understand the basics of object oriented programming and is okay with slow progress(which you should be) you should definitely be able to get started.

But in my honest opinion, the only way to know for sure is by actually trying to develop an app. so just get started now.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Basically I just wanted to build a simple basic app and afterwards I would practice to hone my skills.

Comment: go ahead and do just that, try building an app and learn every time you run into something you don't know yet, that's how you learn best. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks. Also quick question, I see do I need any experience with XML? I know a little XML, but I noticed the android Manifest file is XML file.

Comment: for a basic app especially you won't be using the androidManifest really. XML basics are very straightfoward and i would think you would be able to learn it a long the way.